# Passing the Recoil selectorFamily key outside of the hook

Tags: reactjs, state, recoiljs

I have an atomFamily that stores the status of some devices.

I have a global event listener that fires every time one of my devices updates. It returns the device ID and the status.

My atom and selector family looks like this:

```
export const deviceStatus = atomFamily({
  key: "deviceStatus", // unique ID (with respect to other atoms/selectors)
  default: "disconnected", // default value (aka initial value)
});


export const deviceSelector = selectorFamily({
  key: "deviceSelector",
  get:
    (deviceID) =>
    async ({ get }) => {
      const status = get(deviceStatus(deviceID));
      return status;
    },
  set:
    (deviceID) =>
    async ({ set }, newValue) => {
      set(deviceStatus(deviceID), newValue);
    },
});
```

My question is - how do I update the atomFamily if I don't have the ID before I use my recoil hook.

```
  const [deviceStatus, setDeviceStatus] = useRecoilState(deviceSelector(NO DEVICE ID HERE));
```

Is there any way to update the atomFamily by specifying the key outside of the hook?